# RecyclerView isn't being showed on first launch of the app

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-recyclerview, android-volley

I have a recyclerView in my application where the data is fetched from a web server and stored in the local database after which the list is populated from the local database.
However, when the app is launched after clearing data. The list doesn't get populated, but it is showed when I close the app and open it again.
The data gets inserted in the database on the first launch. However it isn't shown in the recyclerView.

Here is the code:

**Database.java:**

```
void addEmployeeIfNotExistsToDatabase(Employee employee){
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();

    String CHECK_EXISTENCE_EMPLOYEE_QUERY = "SELECT id FROM " + TABLE_EMPLOYEES + ";";
    Cursor existChecker = database.rawQuery(CHECK_EXISTENCE_EMPLOYEE_QUERY, null);

    int existFlag = 0;

    if(existChecker.moveToFirst()){
        do {
            if((existChecker.getInt(existChecker.getColumnIndex("id"))) == (employee.getId())){
                existFlag = 1;
            }
        }while (existChecker.moveToNext());
    }
    existChecker.close();

    if (existFlag == 0){
        //DLog.e("Yes", "Being added");
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

        contentValues.put("id", employee.getId());
        contentValues.put("firstName", employee.getName().split(" ")[0].trim());
        contentValues.put("lastName", employee.getName().split(" ")[1].trim());
        contentValues.put("dateOfBirth", String.valueOf(employee.getDateOfBirth()));
        contentValues.put("joinDate", String.valueOf(employee.getJoinDate()));
        contentValues.put("gender", employee.getGender());
        contentValues.put("emailId", employee.getEmailId());
        contentValues.put("contactNo", employee.getContactNo());
        contentValues.put("alternateContactNo", employee.getAlternateContactNo());
        contentValues.put("bloodGroup", employee.getBloodGroup());
        contentValues.put("experience", employee.getExperience());
        contentValues.put("status", employee.getStatus());
        contentValues.put("designation", employee.getDesignation());
        contentValues.put("temporaryAddressLine1", employee.getTemporaryAddressLine1());
        contentValues.put("temporaryAddressLine2", employee.getTemporaryAddressLine2());
        contentValues.put("temporaryAddressStateId", employee.getTemporaryAddressStateId());
        contentValues.put("temporaryAddressCityId", employee.getTemporaryAddressCityId());
        contentValues.put("temporaryAddressPincode", employee.getTemporaryAddressPincode());
        contentValues.put("permanentAddressLine1", employee.getPermanentAddressLine1());
        contentValues.put("permanentAddressLine2", employee.getPermanentAddressLine2());
        contentValues.put("permanentAddressStateId", employee.getPermanentAddressStateId());
        contentValues.put("permanentAddressCityId", employee.getPermanentAddressCityId());
        contentValues.put("permanentAddressPincode", employee.getPermanentAddressPincode());
        contentValues.put("profilePicture", employee.getProfilePicture());
        contentValues.put("userName", employee.getUserName());
        contentValues.put("checkedIn", employee.getCheckedIn());

        Log.e("checkout", String.valueOf(employee.getCheckedOut()));

        contentValues.put("checkedOut", employee.getCheckedOut());

        database.insert(TABLE_EMPLOYEES, null, contentValues);
    }
    database.close();
}
```

**ListActivity.java:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
    employee_recycler = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    searchqr = findViewById(R.id.search_emp);
    search = findViewById(R.id.searchbtn);

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    employee_recycler.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    database = new Database(getApplicationContext());

    employeeList = new ArrayList<>();
    employeeAdapter = new EmployeeAdapter(getApplicationContext(), new ArrayList<Employee>(), this);
    listener = this;

    employee_recycler.setAdapter(employeeAdapter);

    getLoaderManager().initLoader(1, null, this).forceLoad();
}
@Override
public Loader<List<Employee>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    return new EmployeeLoader(ListActivity.this);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<Employee>> loader, List<Employee> data) {
    employeeAdapter.setEmployees(data);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<List<Employee>> loader) {
    employeeAdapter.setEmployees(new ArrayList<Employee>());
}
```

**EmployeeAdapter.java:**

```
public class EmployeeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<EmployeeAdapter.MyViewHolder>{

private Context context;
private List<Employee> employeeListFiltered = new ArrayList<>();
private EmployeeAdapterListener listener;

class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView employeeName, employeeId;
    CircleImageView employeeImage;

    MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        employeeName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_emp);
        employeeId = itemView.findViewById(R.id.id_emp);
        employeeImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_emp);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                listener.onEmployeeSelected(employeeListFiltered.get(getAdapterPosition()));
            }
        });

        Button checkBtn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkbtn);

        checkBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                listener.onEmployeeSelected(employeeListFiltered.get(getAdapterPosition()));
                Toast.makeText(context, "Punch button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}

public void setEmployees(List<Employee> data) {
    employeeListFiltered.addAll(data);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

EmployeeAdapter(Context context, List<Employee> employeeList, EmployeeAdapterListener listener){
    this.context = context;
    this.listener = listener;
    this.employeeListFiltered = employeeList;
}

@Override
public EmployeeAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.employee_element, parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(EmployeeAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final Employee employee = employeeListFiltered.get(position);
    holder.employeeName.setText(employee.getName());
    holder.employeeId.setText(employee.getUserName());

    //Get status and check with button

    Glide.with(context)
            .load(employee.getProfilePicture())
            .apply(new RequestOptions().placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder_image).error(R.drawable.placeholder_image))
            .into(holder.employeeImage);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return employeeListFiltered.size();
}

void filterList(ArrayList<Employee> filteredEmployeeNames) {
    this.employeeListFiltered = filteredEmployeeNames;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public interface EmployeeAdapterListener {
    void onEmployeeSelected(Employee employee);
}
```

}

**EmployeeLoader.java:**

```
public class EmployeeLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<List<Employee>> {

private Database database;
private Context localContext;
private static final String LOCAL_URL = "http://192.168.1.33:3369/api/v1/employees/c6c2f463db4cb59a6e8bd62783a9f063";

EmployeeLoader(Context context) {
    super(context);
    localContext = context;
    database = new Database(context);
}

@Override
protected void onStartLoading() {
    super.onStartLoading();
}

@Override
public List<Employee> loadInBackground() {
    Log.e("Loader", "Loading in background");
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(localContext);
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, LOCAL_URL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                Log.e("GET request", response.toString());
                JSONObject allEmployees = response.getJSONObject("data");

                Iterator<String> keys = allEmployees.keys();
                while (keys.hasNext()) {
                    String key = keys.next();
                    JSONObject employee = allEmployees.getJSONObject(key);
                    Employee singleEmployee = new Employee();

                    singleEmployee.setId(Integer.parseInt(employee.getString("id")));
                    singleEmployee.setName(employee.getString("firstName") + " " + employee.getString("lastName"));
                    singleEmployee.setDateOfBirth(java.sql.Date.valueOf(employee.getString("dateOfBirth")));
                    singleEmployee.setJoinDate(java.sql.Date.valueOf(employee.getString("joinDate")));
                    singleEmployee.setGender(employee.getString("gender"));
                    singleEmployee.setEmailId(employee.getString("emailId"));
                    singleEmployee.setContactNo(employee.getString("contactNo"));
                    singleEmployee.setAlternateContactNo(employee.getString("alternateContactNo"));
                    singleEmployee.setBloodGroup(employee.getString("bloodGroup"));
                    singleEmployee.setExperience(Float.parseFloat(employee.getString("experience")));
                    singleEmployee.setStatus(employee.getString("status"));
                    singleEmployee.setDesignation(employee.getString("designation"));
                    singleEmployee.setTemporaryAddressLine1(employee.getString("temporaryAddressLine1"));
                    singleEmployee.setTemporaryAddressLine2(employee.getString("temporaryAddressLine2"));
                    singleEmployee.setTemporaryAddressStateId(employee.getString("temporaryAddressStateId"));
                    singleEmployee.setTemporaryAddressCityId(employee.getString("temporaryAddressCityId"));
                    singleEmployee.setTemporaryAddressPincode(employee.getString("temporaryAddressPincode"));
                    singleEmployee.setPermanentAddressLine1(employee.getString("permanentAddressLine1"));
                    singleEmployee.setPermanentAddressLine2(employee.getString("permanentAddressLine2"));
                    singleEmployee.setPermanentAddressStateId(employee.getString("permanentAddressStateId"));
                    singleEmployee.setPermanentAddressCityId(employee.getString("permanentAddressCityId"));
                    singleEmployee.setPermanentAddressPincode(employee.getString("permanentAddressPincode"));
                    singleEmployee.setProfilePicture(employee.getString("profilePicture"));
                    singleEmployee.setUserName(employee.getString("userName"));
                    singleEmployee.setCheckedIn(Integer.parseInt(employee.getString("isCheckedIn")));
                    singleEmployee.setCheckedOut(Integer.parseInt(employee.getString("isCheckedOut")));

                    database.addEmployeeIfNotExistsToDatabase(singleEmployee);
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("Error", error.getMessage());
        }
    });

    requestQueue.add(jsonObjReq);
    return database.populateListFromDatabase();
}
```

}

Comment: the data appears in the second launch?

Comment: Yes, the data appears in the second launch

Comment: then follow one of the options in my answer and your problem will be solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the try catch block inside the loader. I added a `finally` block and used  `deliverResult(database.populateListFromDatabase())` which updated the UI even on the first launch.

Answer (score 2):

You have many options to solve this problem.

- You can use `AsyncTask` `onPostExecute` method to populate the `Recycler view`.
- You can use Activity life cycle methods to populate the `Recycler view` (`onStart, onPause` ... ).
- You can make a **splash screen** and get the data in the **splash screen** then when it's over the data will be displayed in the second `Activity`.

Comment: The last suggestion is my favourite.. You beat me to it!

Comment: I am using an AsyncTaskLoader and I am populating the List<Employee> when the loader calls the OnLoadFinished method. Yet, the list doesn't get populated in the first launch

Comment: refer to one of those answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18414490/loader-returns-no-data-or-an-empty-cursor

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33697991/recyclerview-not-showing-anything-after-updating-adapter-data

Comment: No need to create splash screen. Just run `Asynctask` with `progressdialog` in `onPreExecute()` method. Make rest api volley call in `doInBackground()` method. Lastly check for `employeeList.size()` in `onPostExecute()`  method. If size is !=0 then populate recylerview item by dismissing the `progressdialog`. Otherwise tell the user data list is 0 by dismissing the `progressdialog`.